# Restrict android map marker drag to polyline

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm looking for some suggestions on how I could approach a problem I'm facing with an android SupportMapFragment. I am drawing a polyline on a SupportMapFragment using LatLng co-ordinance stored in my apps db. I am also adding a map marker at the first and last LatLng co-ordinance to signify the start and end of the route. I would like to provide my users with the ability to trim the route by dragging the start and end markers to their desired points on the polyline. The problem I am facing is restricting the path the markers can be dragged across so they can only be moved along the polyline.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried reading the Official Google Documentation for Maps Android API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've been through the documentation but I cannot find a simple way of doing this. The only method I've come up with is adding a OnMarkerDragListener to the map. When either of the markers move, loop through all the points in the polyline to find the closest to the marker position, then reposition the marker to this closest point from the polyline. It just seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

This questions is a little bit old, but I hope others would find this answer useful.

boolean PolyUtil.isLocationOnEdge will help you determine wether a point overlaps a Polygon or Polyline on the map.

```
public class RestrictedMarkerDragActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {

    private static final float WIDTH = 4;
    private static final double TOLERANCE_IN_METERS = 3.0;

    private GoogleMap map;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private Polyline polyline;
    private Marker marker;
    private LatLng positionOnPolyline;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.map = googleMap;

        List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
        points.add(new LatLng(19.35853391311947, -99.15182696733749));
        points.add(new LatLng(19.34384275931999, -99.1546209261358));

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.color(Color.CYAN);
        polylineOptions.width(WIDTH);
        polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        polyline.setPoints(points);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.draggable(true);
        markerOptions.position(points.get(0));
        marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        positionOnPolyline = new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude);

        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(points.get(0), 15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        //Nothing to do here

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        //If the marker overlaps the polyline, polyline width gets bigger and marker position gets updated,
        //else, polyline width remains the same
        if(PolyUtil.isLocationOnEdge(marker.getPosition(), polyline.getPoints(), true, TOLERANCE_IN_METERS)) {
            polyline.setWidth(WIDTH * 3);
            positionOnPolyline = new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude);
        } else {
            polyline.setWidth(WIDTH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //We set the marker to its last known position over the polyline
        marker.setPosition(positionOnPolyline);
        //We set polyline width to its original
        polyline.setWidth(WIDTH);
    }

}
```

Comment: The width addition in the answer is really looking good thanks for that

Comment: Bro how would you do this if you had multiple polylines to compare against?